# Can memory be freed if its pointer has changed type?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

Given a memory allocation:

```
struct typeA *p = malloc(sizeof(struct typeA));
```

and then somewhere, for example, in a function, there are 2 choices:

```
void func(void *q)
{
     ....
    free(q);
}

void func(void *q)
{
    ....

    struct typeA *pp = (struct typeA *)q;
    free(pp); 
}
```

Both of them are OK or just the second is OK? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are ok. `free()` only cares about the address that is stored in the pointer and that does not change when casting.

Comment: Well, that depends on the representation and alignment requirements of the base type of the pointer. `(intptr_t)p` is not necessarily the same as `(intptr_t)(struct TypeA *)pp`.

Comment: Not all pointers have the same size, this is platform dependent, so cast pointer may change the value of the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct typeA *pp = (struct typeA *)q;
```

This typecast is unecessary. Also, `free` argument's type is a pointer to `void`. Therefore, the function cannot have any idea of the type of the lvalue which is used to access the object `*pp`. It just receives a raw pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is.

As `free()` is waiting for a void pointer, your compiler will convert your pointer to `void *` if needed.

Comment: It's not that the compiler will cast it - there's no cast involved, only an implicit conversion from `T *` to `void *`.

Comment: And it the sizeof(T *) differs from sizeof(void *)?

Comment: `void *` is always compatible with any data pointer type, and automatic, implicit conversion from and to it occurs.

Comment: hum, I used the wrong expression, It was not clear to me the difference between implicit cast and conversion, going to fix the answer. I though that an "implicit cast" was a "conversion", but there is no such thing.

Comment: There's no such thing as "implicit cast" :) There's explicit type conversion which is called casting, and implicit type conversion which is called coalescing or promotion.